# GCP Datastore times out on large download

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm using Objectify to access my GCP Datastore set of Entites. I have a full list of around 22000 items that I need to load into the frontend:

```
List<Record> recs = ofy().load().type(Record.class).order("-sync").list();
```

The number of records has recently increased and I get an error from the backend:
*com.google.apphosting.runtime.HardDeadlineExceededError: This request (00000185caff7b0c) started at 2023/01/19 17:06:58.956 UTC and was still executing at 2023/01/19 17:08:02.545 UTC.*

I thought that the move to Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode last year would have fixed this problem.

My only solution is to break down the load() into batches using 2 or 3 calls to my Ofy Service.
Is there a better way to grab all these Entities in one go?
Thanks
Tim

Comment: Do you still get the problem if you grab an iterator() (instead of a list) and set the chunk size to something reasonable, like 1000?

Comment: Thanks - I've not tried that. Do you have a link to a good example of Objectify Iterator() as the docs aren't clear (to me :-( )

Comment: The query object is Iterable. Just call `iterator()` instead of `list()`. The `chunk()` method determines how many items are processed per fetch; `list()` means "read everything into memory at once" so it tries to chunk the whole set. So try `ofy().load().type(Record.class).order("-sync").chunk(500).iterator()`.

Comment: Have you tried with paginating the records with `.offset()` and `limit()` ?

Comment: Thanks stickfigure, I thought the .iterator() was working, but still getting the same HardDeadlineExceededError from the back end when I call my REST function using a standard $http.get() function. I guess my only option is to make multiple calls to the backend and $get them in chunks. Any other idea would be welcome. Thanks!